tensorflow and keras on vscode on mac with python
I'm trying to get tensorflow.keras.layers to work on VSCode but everything I try does not seem to work and I keep getting a warning saying that Import "tensorflow.keras.layers" could not be resolved Pylance. I've made a virtual environment and pip installed both tensorflow and keras and it tells me requirement already satisfied. I'm not really sure what to do. I have tensorflow version 2.17.0 and keras 3.4.1. I've seen questions similar to my problem on here but they haven't really helped me. I'm also on a Mac though I'm not sure if that changes anything.
I've made a virtual environment and pip installed both tensorflow and keras and it tells me requirement already satisfied. I'm not really sure what to do. I have tensorflow version 2.17.0 and keras 3.4.1. Honestly after creating a virtual environment I thought everything would work out but it still has the same problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
